# Explain some tips of bash

Tags: bash, pid

I get a piece of code for PID file control.

The style of programmers, I don't understand..

I don't know -->

Use of && on

```
[[ $mypid -ne $procpid ]] **&&**
```

And relaunch ourselves properly (does not work on MacosX)

```
$0 $@ &
```

Code complete...

```
function createpidfile() {
  mypid=$1
  pidfile=$2
  #Close stderr, don't overwrite existing file, shove my pid in the lock file.
  $(exec 2>&-; set -o noclobber; echo "$mypid" > "$pidfile") 
  [[ ! -f "$pidfile" ]] && exit #Lock file creation failed
  procpid=$(<"$pidfile")
  [[ $mypid -ne $procpid ]] && {
    #I'm not the pid in the lock file
    # Is the process pid in the lockfile still running?
    isrunning "$pidfile" || {
      # No.  Kill the pidfile and relaunch ourselves properly.
      rm "$pidfile"
      $0 $@ &
    }
    exit
  }
}
```

I'm lost

Comment: That code looks pretty good. I don't understand why they did line 4 of the function as they did. That should be an error unless one of those commands produces a valid command name, which they shouldn't, and it should be quoted rather than relying on word-splitting. They probably meant it to be a subshell with no preceding `$` sign to isolate the noclobber. Also, don't use the `function name() {` syntax. If it's Bash just use `name()`. If you're doing some unusual ksh/bash polyglot library, use `function name {`.

Comment: To properly protect the arguments with whitespace, change `$0 $@ &` to `"$0" "$@" &` -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters

Answer (score 1):

`[[ ! -f "$pidfile" ]] && exit` means "if there is no file called $pidfile then exit" (using the [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)) - `exit` will not be evaluated if the file exists.

`$0 $@ &`:

- `$0` - the first argument in the command line (meaning the executable itself);
- `$@` - all the remaining arguments passed onto the command line;
- `&` - send the process to background after the launch.

Answer (score 1):

```
    command1 && command2
```

command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.

`$0` is the name of the actual binary.

`$@` are all parameters.

and the closing `&` sends the process to the background.

Everything is documented in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) See e.g. section `3.4.2 Special Parameters`

Comment: _command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of_ **zero** -> should be **non-zero** (since if `command1` evaluates to zero, there is no sense in evaluating `command2` - the expression is guaranteed to be false).

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov - that line is a copy-paste from the bash-manual, but yes, you are of course correct.

Comment: disagree, bash manual is correct as is. try this for example `false &&  echo got here` VS. `true && echo got here2`. And, `false; echo $?; true ; echo $?`. Good luck to all.

Comment: @AoeAoe is correct, and so is the bash manual. In bash, `exit 0` means success, and evaluates to `true` in that context.

Answer (score 1):

1. `&&` is a logical **AND**.

   If the condition `[[ $mypid -ne $procpid ]]` is true, the code in the block `{...}` gets executed.
2. `$0 $@ &` restarts the script in the background (with the same arguments).

   - `$0` is the command that invoked the script
   - `$@` is the list of all arguments passed to the script
   - `&` indicates the previous command should be executed in the background

Answer (score 1):

It's [boolean short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) - if the bit before the `&&` (and) operator evaluates to be `false` then there's no need to execute the second part (the block between `{` and `}`. The same trick is used with the `||` operator, which will only execute the second block if the first block returned `false`.